# What methods can I use to rearrange the order of javascript function execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication, deferred-execution

### How to rearrange javascript function execution order independent of include order.

**A question that assists, but doesn't completely answer my question:**  [Can you have multiple $(document).ready(function() sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327756/can-you-have-multiple-document-readyfunction-sections) (The answer is yes, and they execute in the order that they are added to jQuery.ready()).

I am trying to make my javascript logged-in/not logged-in aware, for convenient notification purposes, on my BBG [ninjawars.net](http://test.ninjawars.net).  I was hoping to use a simple system of having the server-side php write out a javascript function call `setLoggedIn()` when a page is logged in, and write out a call to `clearLoggedIn()` when a page is being viewed while logged out:

```
<head>
...
        <!-- All the global ninjawars javascript, defines the setLoggedIn(), clearLoggedIn(), and modifyPageLayout() functions and (currently) calls modifyPageLayout() within jQuery.ready() -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/nw.js"></script>

 {if $logged_in} // Server-side check.
   <script type="text/javascript">
     <!--
      setLoggedIn();
     // -->
   </script>
 {else} // Server-side check found that the user was not logged in.
   <script type="text/javascript">
     <!--
      clearLoggedIn();
     // -->
   </script>
 {/if}
</head>
```

### Problems:

Currently, the order is:

- define setLoggedIn() and clearLoggedIn() globally (in nw.js)
- Add page/information modification code, lets call it modifyPageLayout() that needs to be informed of logged-in/logged-out to jQuery.ready() (in nw.js)
- Call setLoggedIn() or clearLoggedIn() inline in script tags on the page.

I don't know how to make sure that the calls to setLoggedIn() or clearLoggedIn() occur before modifyPageLayout(), which is currently wrapped in a jQuery.ready() block, and would thus run whenever the DOM loaded.

- If I added setLoggedIn() and clearLoggedIn() to jQuery.ready() blocks, they would be executed in the order added, thus the order would become: `modifyPageLayout()`, then `setLoggedIn()` or `setLoggedOut()` so all in jQuery.ready() blocks doesn't accomplish the intent.
- setLoggedIn() and clearLoggedIn() currently rely on code defined nw.js, so I can't call them 
  before including nw.js.

### One potential solution:

I could delay the modifyPageLayout function by writing it as:

```
modifyFunction = modifyPageLayout; // Non-executed first-class function variable. (created in nw.js)

setLoggedIn(); // inline in the head of the page
modifyFunction(); // inline in the head of the page
```

Anyone have other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe Im missing something, so sorry if I am.

But for setLoggedIn() and clearLoggedIn(), wouldnt you want them to happen any time someone clicks to log in or out? So then you could add an event handler inside the document.ready to deal with that.

Presumably, the fact that something happens when someone is logged in or out could be used to the modifyPageLayout function to decide what things show and how.

Anyway, Im not sure if the question is more complicated than that

Comment: I don't really see any useful client-side click triggers to use to run isLoggedIn() because even if they click "login", that could result in a failed login, which would make isLoggedIn() as a lie.

isLoggedIn() and clearLoggedIn() are switched between by the server depending upon whether php has the correct login credentials in session.  I'll try to clarify that in the question.

Comment: Maybe use document.ready calling setLoggedIn() and window.load for modifyPageLayout(), then?

Discussion about the difference here:
http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/

Comment: All th' feedback I'm gonna get, I guess.