# is using javascript document ready twice in one document ok?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a header on my webpage that contains the some javascript for some jquery plugins i am using. These plugins are used on a bunch of pages so I just include them in the header document that is included in everyone one of my pages.

There is one page however that I would like to include some other javascript but is only needed on this one page. can i use the document ready function a second time on the same page or is that poor form?

I don't want to include the javascript on everypage as it is not needed and would be a waste to load on every page.

Comment: nothing really wrong with it. the 2nd usage will just be added to the ready queue and won't overwrite/replace the first one.

Comment: As long as they are not within each other it is fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## YES

The [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Multiple_$%28document%29.ready%28%29) are clear that this is fine.

Comment: Yes, but please don't. Think about the poor guys who will have to refactor the application.

Comment: Sackling - I agree with @karim - if it's the same document, then you should really consolidate into one handler

Answer (score 3):

no nothing wrong it will be executed in the order it is specified

here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/LKuz2/7/

Comment: Not sure if you're aware of this; but `e` is not an event object but rather the jQuery function. (Your naming may be a little ambiguous.)

Comment: @pimvdb you are right i was not aware of it tnx for correcting, updated the fiddle

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use it multiple times.  It binds each function to the triggered event of the document being ready.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, keeping in mind that:

- Your code will be less readable.
- You will end up with multiple function scopes with each block. So variables you create in one closure will not be visible from other ones.

Recommendation: If you think you *need* multiple `$(document).ready(` blocks, you are probably wrong. Take time to re-work your solution to something more maintainable.

Erm, and this has been covered here before. More than once. By Me. How embarrassing :)

- [What are the side effects (if any) of multiple $(document).ready() in an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538161/what-are-the-side-effects-if-any-of-multiple-document-ready-in-an-html-pa/)
- [Can you have multiple $(document).ready(function(){ ... }); sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327756/can-you-have-multiple-document-readyfunction-sections/)