# Is it allowed to have more than one document.ready in a page?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery - multiple $(document).ready … ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263385/jquery-multiple-document-ready)

Does it matter if we have more than one `document.ready` in a page? because I have some JavaScript files which all of them have this phrase inside. Will it cause problem? Any logical or syntax problem?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that is fine.

> One more great thing about $(document).ready() that I didn't mention in my previous post is that you can use it more than once. In fact, if you don't care at all about keeping your code small, you could litter your javascript file with them

[Source](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/multiple-document-ready).