# Javascript document.ready in multiple files with Gulp

Tags: javascript, jquery, build, gulp

I'm using gulp to concat a bunch of individual js files into one uglified, minified js file. It works fine.

Since all these individual js files all have a jQuery `document.ready`, is that good? The end result would be having several `document.ready`s in the minified version.

What is the best practice for this?

Comment: And this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874015/implications-of-having-multiple-document-ready-functions-across-multiple-js-f

Comment: @lapint that answered one question, how bout the other? the one where i asked if it's best practice with gulp to do that?

Comment: Afraid then half the post is a dupe, and the other half is asking for opinions (the answer will be "it depends on your specific context").