# Multiple DOM Ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery - multiple $(document).ready …?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263385/jquery-multiple-document-ready)

I have my JS code that is using jQuery within the jQuery Document Ready IE:

```
$(function() {

});
```

I am running multiple jQuery scripts on the page and all are contained within one `$(function() { });` is there any reason I should break the scripts into multiple ready handlers? IE:

```
$(function() {
      // First Script
});

$(function() {
      // Second Script
});

//etc.
```

or is it okay to have multplie scripts within one? IE:

```
$(function() {
      // First Script
      //Second Script
      //etc. 
});
```

I assume one is just fine but I want to ensure there are no reasons I should use multiple ones.

Comment: 1 Ready handler. No reason for multiple unless they're in different files.

Comment: you can do it but technically speaking you would only need one

Comment: See [JQuery - multiple $(document).ready …?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5263440/1889273)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could have multiple `document.ready` handlers in your script(s), jQuery will merge them into a single one before executing anyway. But it's really not necessary to have many document.ready handlers. One is enough. And if you put your scripts always at the end of your DOM, just before the closing `</body>` tag you don't need to use any document.ready handlers.

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    ... your CSS references come here
</head>
<body>
    ... the markup of the body comes here ...

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // you don't need to use any document.ready handlers here =>
        // you could directly write your scripts inline or reference them
        // as external resources. At this stage the DOM will be ready
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is `should` not `could` and you definitely `should not`.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: How is it a "definitely"? Maybe someone likes separation.

Comment: He might use some Java-Webframework where this could happen (e.g. Wicket - when more than one Component wants to add some stuff in domready)

Answer (score 4):

It makes absolutely no difference with regards to how it works.

However, it can be useful for organision.

On the other hand, it means more jQuery has to run.

Comment: Why would it have *more* to run?

Comment: @Dhaviat Pandya Because everytime you call `$(function(){` you build a jQuery wrapper for the DOM ready event, which causes overhead.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, that's not true. jQuery merges all `$(function() { });` handlers you have written into a single document ready subscription before executing. There is no overhead.

Comment: It's still having to call `$()`, which works out what you give it (in this case a function) and what to do with it. That's the overhead.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: That's a little misleading. The amount of time it takes to "build" a wrapper is negligible, and I don't think jQuery even builds one for that particular case.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: [No wrapper-building involved for multiple calls.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L165)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap all of your scripts/functions inside of a single ready event or you can simply place all of your scripts after your html and then avoid having to wait for a ready event because the DOM is already loaded by this point.

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Style sheets Go Here -->
</head>
<body>
    <!--HTML Goes Here -->
    <!-- Scripts Go Here -->
</body>
</html>
```