# Multiple Document Ready Calls - not working

Tags: jquery, document-ready

According to this question here:
[jQuery - multiple $(document).ready ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263385/jquery-multiple-document-ready)

When there are multiple document ready calls each call will be ran in turn.
However I've just followed an issue on my site down to a case where I have multiple calls and the second one isn't working.

I've reproduced this in the following JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/h7q9Z/

As is there are two document ready statements.  If you hit the create button the form is submitted.

Remove the first ready statement like so
http://jsfiddle.net/h7q9Z/1/

and hit create and the form submission is prevented.

Why is this?

Code copied as required:
Script:

```
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            });

        });


$(function(e) {

        $("#mainForm").submit(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
            return false;

        });
    });
```

Html:

```
<form id="mainForm" action="nonExistantPage.asp" method="get">
    Funky Thing:<input></input>
            <button id="submitButton">Create</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the second `});` and your code will compile.

```
       jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        });

    });
```