# jQuery Calendar Date Picker on External JS file

Tags: jquery, html, forms, calendar, picker

I wonder what did I do wrong, my calendar date picker only works when I implement the JavaScript code inside my html page like this

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".datepick" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

But not working when I put the code externally.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".datepick" ).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: How do you include your external js file?

Comment: @pXL Here is how I include the external js file. <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

Comment: and where do you include jQuery ?

Comment: @pXL Can I have 2 different functions with $(document).ready(function()... each inside external js file? If I disabled the other, the datepicker works.

Comment: @pXL This is the other JS function inside the same script.js file. $(document).ready(function() { $('#example').dataTable(); });

Comment: "Can I have 2 different..." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263385/jquery-multiple-document-ready