# Two scripts won't work at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is probably a very simple explanation for this (and likely a much cleaner way to do it), but I'm new and can't quite figure it out. Any assistance would help the learning process...

I have one script that displays one div or another based (`show` instead of `hide`) on what a user selects from a dropdown list. Like so:

```
var PickDiv = (function(){

var _obj = {};

var hideShow = function(elem){
    if($(elem).val() === '1'){
          $("#slider_action").show();
          $("#slider_dollar").hide();
        }else if($(elem).val() === '2'){
          $("#slider_dollar").show();    
           $("#slider_action").hide();
        }else{
          $("#slider_dollar, #slider_action").hide();
        }
};

_obj.checkValue = function(){
    hideShow($('#build_opt'))
};

var events = function(){
    $('#build_opt').change(function(){
       hideShow(this);
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    events ();
    checkValue ();
});

return _obj;

}());
```

This works great and displays the right div based on what is selected from the dropdown. I thought I could reuse this same idea later in my code to have the same effect. Once the div is displayed (after making a selection related to script above), I need to provide another dropdown with additional options. The user will select one of these and then a div will display. So, I figured, I could use something like this:

```
var RunRate = (function(){

var _obj2 = {};

var hideShow_2 = function(elem_2){
    if($(elem_2).val() === '6'){
          $("#db_sign").show();
          $("#app_down", "#in_redem", "#site_vis", "#cont_ent" ).hide();
        }else if($(elem_2).val() === '7'){
          $("#app_down").show();    
        else{
          $("#app_down", "#in_redem", "#site_vis", "#db_sign", "#cont_ent" ).hide();
        }
};

_obj2.checkValue_2 = function(){
    hideShow_2($('#action_type_2'))
};

var events_2 = function(){
    $('#action_type_2').change(function(){
       hideShow_2(this);
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    events_2 ();
    checkValue_2 ();
});

return _obj2;

}());
```

Of course, this doesn't work. I tried a number of different things with no luck. Note that if I exclude the first script from my code, the second script works fine, so I know it works. I'm guessing it has something to do with the two scripts sharing a variable or something about jquery that I'm clearly missing.

Any help would be appreciated. Overall, looking to be able to do a number of these types of dependent dropdowns without interfering with one another.

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE:**

Note that if in the second script, I replace:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

with

```
$( window ).load(function() {
```

then the problem is solved. So, clearly the problem is related to the document.ready interfering with each other, but I don't know how to fix this without this "hack" above especially if I want to use more of these dependent dropdowns. Is there a way to pass a different variable and call that instead of `document`?

**UPDATE 2**

Figured out the problem...my original code was throwing an error due to an undefined reference (`checkValue`). That error was causing the document ready to not work in the second function. Referenced a more detailed explanation in my answer below.

Comment: Are there any errors in your Javascript console?

Comment: Can you throw together a JSFiddle to show your problem?

Comment: I guess you should only have one ```$(document).ready(function(){...}``` in your code. Try to combine the two into one and it should be fine.

Comment: @JustinWood Just one related to this: "Uncaught ReferenceError: checkValue is not defined". That's related to the first script, which works fine though.

Comment: Try combining the document ready functions and moving outside the enclosing functions?

Comment: FYI You can have more than one $(document).ready(...), useful if you have multiple JS files included in your page.

Comment: This might sound stupid, but are you referencing correctly, shouldn't it be `_obj2.checkValue_2();` ? Looking at your code logically second function shouldn't fire because it's not referenced in current context.

Comment: @skmasq That doesn't work. Either script works on its own, but together there's a problem, so I don't think it's related to that. I tried, but didn't help.

Comment: @NeilNeyman Open to give it a try, but I can't quite figure out how to "nest" everything quite right. Tried a few ways, but keep breaking both scripts. Can you give a quick example?

Comment: @jonmrich I read some of your comments, I would suggest you to check out requirejs http://requirejs.org/ , this way you could manage dependencies and execute everything you need at once.

Comment: Following this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263385/jquery-multiple-document-ready , `.ready()` acts on first come first served basis.

Comment: Another suggestion, is to insert `console.log()` functions in each function call, so you would know the sequence and/or if they're called at all.

Comment: @skmasq That question helped...but it isn't a first come, first served problem. The problem was that my code was throwing an error (undefined reference), which won't allow the document ready function to work properly. I fixed that error and now I can use a number of document ready functions without interference. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I'm thinking it was because you wrote this `checkValue();` instead of this `_obj.checkValue();` ?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12907417/989722) to a related question pointed out by @skmasq. @JustinWood was onto something with his comment on my original question. Turns out that my scripts were throwing an error (`"Uncaught ReferenceError: checkValue is not defined"`), which was not allowing the document ready function to work properly.

Here's the critical part of the  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12907417/989722) :

> It is important to note that each jQuery() call must actually return. If an exception is thrown in one, subsequent (unrelated) calls will never be executed.
>
> This applies regardless of syntax. You can use jQuery(), jQuery(function() {}), $(document).ready(), whatever you like, the behavior is the same. If an early one fails, subsequent blocks will never be run.

Comment: I knew it. GZ Figuring it out. I would suggest give more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that $(document).ready() overwrites the initial job? It doesn't matter if you use different functions/variable names ...$(document).ready is the same ...

Comment: You can have multiple $(document).ready as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/TZHNM/

Comment: Could be, but not sure what to try in order to test this out.

Comment: Just added an update to my and I think you're onto something @Jerez. UPDATE:

Note that if in the second script, I replace:

    `$(document).ready(function(){`

with

    `$( window ).load(function() {`

then the problem is solved. So, clearly the problem is related to the document.ready interfering with each other, but I don't know how to fix this without this "hack" above especially if I want to use more of these dependent dropdowns. Is there a way to pass a different variable and call that instead of document?