# Spree: Do JQuery events need registration?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, spree

Hello to the Community,

I want a change in an HTML `select` tag to trigger a Javascript event in my Spree application.

The view contains a collection_select instruction resulting in the following HTML:

```
<select id="dummy_id" name="something">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="1">Case1</option>
    <option value="2">Case3</option>
    <option value="3">Case3</option>
</select>
```

I wrote the following Javascript function:

```
$('#dummy_id').change(function () {
    alert("It works");
});
```

I checked in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Albert_Anstett/PtzKz/1/) that the code indeed works.

When I run the application, the event is not triggered. I googled a lot to try and find documentation regarding a possible registration.

Question: does the event need some sort of a registration? If yes, where to place it and what should this code look like ? If not, any clue as to why it works fine in jsfiddle but not in RAILS_ENV="development" ?

Kind regards !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your jQuery code into an ondocumentready (`$(document).ready()`) function, because jQuery's selectors will only work, when the DOM is constructed and can be traversed, otherwise something like `$('#select-product-in-persomodel_form')` will result in an empty array.

In jsFiddle you can specify when your JS code should be executed (dropdown in the left menu).
You seem to have chosen "`No wrap - in <body>`", that will result in you code added as a script element last in the body, not wrapped in any $(document).ready() or $(window).load()

Calling unwrapped selectors in this place is by no means safe - the DOM is not ready at this point - but might work depending on your browser and luck. 
If you change this to "`No wrap - in <head>`" your code will stop working at all, because while parsing the `<head>` your elements will definitely not have been defined.

As for your other question: You can have multiple `$(document).ready()` without worries, they will be executed in order of their calls. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263385/jquery-multiple-document-ready).

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple ones, but it's not always the neatest thing to do. Try not to overuse them, as it will seriously affect readability. Other than that , it's perfectly legal. See the below:

Like we can have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('first one!');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('second one!');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('third one!');
});
```

but we should do this as below:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('first one!');
        alert('second one!');
        alert('third one!');
    });
```

but when we have reason where we are in situation like we need to use it again, then we can use it definitely. However, I don't think you can know in which way they will be executed.

for reference you should go through this ... [Multiple $(document).ready()](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/multiple-document-ready/)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: the JS code needs to be changed from:

```
$('#dummy_id').change(function () {
    alert("It works");
});
```

to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select-product-in-persomodel_form').change(function() {
    alert("Updating the variants selector for Anacondano");
    $("#persomodels-variant-select").html(" <%= escape_javascript(render 'variant_select') %>");
  });
});
```

Caution: I assume that one Rails application can hold several `$(document).ready` entries. This is a point that I still need to check. Input welcome.