# jQuery: How to call function from inside var on document ready?

Tags: jquery, syntax, document-ready

I have a following function.

```
var sectionSize = {
    onReady: function ($) {
        var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
        $("#masthead").height(viewportHeight);
    }
}
```

There will be another function inside **var sectionSize** later. I want the **function onReady** to be called on **document.ready**. I learned that to do this, I have to use following code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( sectionSize.onReady );
```

This works perfectly, doing what I need. But **I already have a function document.ready there**, which already contains another initializing function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    (function() {
        ...
        });
    })( jQuery );
});
```

I think to have document.ready twice in the file is nonsence but I am not sure, how to combine these two, so it both initialize the original code and do the sectionSize.onReady function. 
Anybody help? Thank you!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having multiple document ready calls. Additionally, `(function () {})()` inside a document ready is redundant. The issues it tries to resolve are already resolved by the call to `jQuery.fn.ready`.

Comment: Check this. It's fine.
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263385/jquery-multiple-document-ready

Comment: Alternately, if you want to combine the two, combine the two.  I think it's easier to understand when it's all in one place.  Call `sectionSize.onReady` and whatever you have inside the other one inside the same `jQuery( document ).ready();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly legal to register multiple `jQuery(document).ready` functions.  They will be invoked in the order in which they were registered.