# Why document ready does not work for kendo controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Please try the following code for example:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function DateOfBirth_Change() {
    var input = document.getElementById("DateOfBirth").value;
    document.getElementById("spanDateOfBirth").innerHTML = input;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    DateOfBirth_Change();
});

</script>

<input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date of Birth: must be a date." data-val-required="*" id="DateOfBirth" name="DateOfBirth" type="date" value="24/10/1984" />
<script>
    jQuery(function(){jQuery("#DateOfBirth").kendoDatePicker({"change":DateOfBirth_Change,"format":"dd/MM/yyyy","parseFormats":["dd/MM/yyyy"],"min":new Date(1900,0,1,0,0,0,0),"max":new Date(2099,11,31,0,0,0,0)});});
</script>
<span id="spanDateOfBirth" style="padding-left: 25px;"></span>
```

It does not work on page load if the document ready function is defined above kendo control...But if it's below, it works fine... Why is this so?

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? And if so, could you post the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you have set value of `<input type=date..` as `"24/10/1984"` and which is in wrong format according to `HTML5 input date type`. Refer - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp, http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#dates-and-times

When in `document.ready`, you have invoked `document.getElementById("DateOfBirth").value`, it gave you blank, as `input type="date"` has a value in incorrect format and when that typecasted to date it got blank.  See the attached example.

Definitely both way ( if you put `document.ready` first or last )it will work. You need to use following `html` markup for this.

`<input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date of Birth: must be a date." data-val-required="*" id="DateOfBirth" name="DateOfBirth" type="date" value="1984-10-24" />`

**Why it worked when you put document.ready last**  - because, `kendodatepicker` made proper initialization and set correct date, and when doc.ready fired , it is able to get value and set.

**Note**:- `document.ready()` and `(jQuery(){})` are same as `document.ready` and they execute serially, that is why it worked when you put `document.ready` at last code block. - [jQuery - multiple $(document).ready ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263385/jquery-multiple-document-ready)

To make sure you understand , why it does not work, i am giving following example.

```js
function getincdate() {
  alert($("#incorrect_dt").val());
}

function getcdate() {
  alert($("#correct_dt").val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Incorrect date -
<input type="date" id="incorrect_dt" value="24/10/1984" /> 
<input type="button" value="Get inccorect date" onclick="getincdate()" />
<br />
you can see above, value is not set here, but with .kendodatepicker, it worked, but after you do .kendo... 
<br/>
Correct date-
<input type="date" id="correct_dt" value="1984-10-24" />
<input type="button" value="Get correct date" onclick="getcdate()" />
```