# Combining multiple jquery document.ready scripts

Tags: jquery, document-ready

I have two scripts.  One is for jquery forms and the other to refresh a div at intervals.

Without the refresh script the jquery posts work.  When I add the refresh script, the forms submit the default way but the refresh works.  I assume the solution is to combine them.  My efforts failed.  Help!

UPDATE: Each script works as long as the other is not in the code, too.  Attempts to merge also fail.  I've added the `<form>` for reference.  To clarify, when both are present or combined the default /GET occurs instead of the ajax executing.  The refresh always works.  I've confirmed submitting the form before the refresh occurs makes no difference.

UPDATE 2: If I move the form submit code into the DIV that is refreshed I can run it properly BUT only until the refresh occurs.  After the first ajax refresh the form begins submitting traditionally.

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".col-xs-4").load(\"statisticsDiv");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $(".col-xs-4").load('/statisticsDiv?randval='+ Math.random());
    }, 10000);
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
  });
</script>")); 
 
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() {
    });
  });
</script>
```

```
<form id="myForm" action="http://192.168.1.150:2560/" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="cleaner" value="on" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Toggle" /> 
</form>
```

SOLVED:  Added this to rebind the element returned after the DIV refresh.   Might not be correct way but it works.  Refining suggestions?

```
    $(document).ajaxStop(function() { 
      $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() {
      });
    });
```

Comment: Have a look at this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263385/jquery-multiple-document-ready

Comment: There are some syntax errors in your code e.g. `.load(\"statisticsDiv");` and `</script>"));`.

Comment: The script is buried in C and I need to escape there. I missed them when I pulled it out to post here.

Answer (score 0):

...like this?

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".col-xs-4").load(\"statisticsDiv");

    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $(".col-xs-4").load('/statisticsDiv?randval='+ Math.random());
    }, 10000);

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Still refreshes at 10sec but the GET form uses default method, not jquery