# Is it efficient to use more than one Jquery initialization function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I should have named my question "Jquery initialization function" which includes Jquery methods and variables. Is it efficient to use following examples? Or should I use all methods in one Jquery initialization function ?

```
<script> 
   /* 1 */
    $(function() {
     //methods 
    });
</script>
<script>
   /* 2 */
    $(function() {
       //methods
    });
</script>
```

Comment: No need to have multiple script tags . if that was what you meant

Comment: You can use as many as you can. But using one is good and not relying on jQuery can also be considered.

Comment: @YoYo I am using for readability.

Comment: @osdev : You can separate the functions using comments that can add to readability

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple initialization blocks are okay. They are perfectly valid, and don't add any overhead. In fact many of the plugins have their own `$(function() {}` blocks. But, there are some implications that can be caused by this, for example, subsequent blocks will not be run if one block has any error. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12907417/2019247) for more details.

You can check out the answers, and follow the discussions [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263385/jquery-multiple-document-ready).

And, lastly, it is always a good practice to search first for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry at this stage. Unless you are doing 100 and 100s of initialsation calls this will most likely not be your bottleneck.

Things like DOM manipulation are far more expensive.