# Redundant events in your javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have written multiple functions in jQuery.

**My client is saying, there are currently redundant events in your JavaScript. Please consolidate all the code that should occur within a single event.**

I am still learning jQuery. Please help.

Thanks.

```js
'use strict';

$(function() {
 $( '.task-list' ).on( 'click', 'li.list', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('completed' );
 });
});

$(function() {
 setTimeout(function(){
  $('body').addClass('loaded');
 }, 3000);
});

$(function() {
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
 $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});

$(function(){
 $('.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('open');
 }, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('open');
 });
});
```

Comment: Don’t forget to accept an answer if it was clear enough for you, or ask for details in comments

Answer (score 2):

I think you should bind all the events within `document.ready` event.

As saild on jquery's official site :

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."
>   jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside
>   $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object
>   Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

So do something like this :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //your code goes here 
    //bind the all events and do other stuff
});

or 

$(function(){
    //your code goes here 
    //bind the all events and do other stuff
});
```

Don't repeat it multiple times.

Comment: `$(function(){}) ` is same thing...read the docs more thoroughly yourself

Comment: Yes, its same thing. But you don't need to use it again and again.

Comment: What does that have to do with how you answered? Answer is still misleading

Comment: he has used $(function(){ ... }) multiple time to bind events to different DOM element. while its just required only one time

Comment: Doesn't say anything about that in the answer....answer implies that OP code is wrong , but it is not. Agree can be managed inside one ready handler but can also have numerous ones

Comment: My client is saying, there are currently redundant events in your JavaScript. Please consolidate all the code that should occur within a single event. that is what he is asking

Comment: But that is not what was answered....you answered stating to use `document.ready` which is already being used..

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
'use strict';

$(function() {
    $( '.task-list' ).on( 'click', 'li.list', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('completed' );
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').addClass('loaded');
    }, 3000);

    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

    $('.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('open');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('open');
    });
});
```

the `$(function() {...})` you are using is in fact a short-hand for `$(document).ready(function() {...})`. This method allows you to check if your document is fully loaded before applying jquery. Doing it for each block of your code means that each time you add a new listener, which is not what you want. More on multiple call to this function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5263385/6320039).

See more about this function on [JQuery documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)