# Dropdown trigger change function to fetch dates to disable in datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

I have a dropdown of staff names and  StaffId. This is wired to an appointment business logic. I am trying to trigger a select change so that setting dates stored in database will be made unavailable in the connected jquery datetimepicker.  I have assembled the code below which seems not working. Could anyone point me to the right direction. Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            getdates();
        });

        var unavailableDates;
        $(document).ready( function getdates() {

            $("#StaffId").change(function (e) {
                $this = $(e.target);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Appointment/GetOffdays",
                        data: { StaffId: $this.val()  },
                        //contentType: "application/json"
                        success: function (data) {
                            debugger;
                            unavailableDates = data;

                            $(".jqueryui-marker-datepicker").datepicker({
                                dateFormat: "dd/M/yy",
                                changeMonth: true,
                                changeYear: false,
                                yearRange: "-1:+0",
                                //beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
                                minDate: new Date(@(ViewBag.year+","+ViewBag.month+","+ViewBag.day)),
                                maxDate: new Date(@(ViewBag.eyear+","+ViewBag.emonth+","+ViewBag.eday)),

                                beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                                    var dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
                                    debugger;
                                    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
                                        return [true, ""];
                                    } else {
                                        return [false, "myclass", "Unavailable"];
                                    }
                                }
                                });
                            },
                             dataType: "json",
                            traditional: true,
                            })


                }

           )
            $('#StaffId').trigger('change');
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reduce the complexity of your code I stripped out the content of `getdates` and replaced it with a simple log(), which I will put below. If I execute this page as is, the anonymous function sent to `$(document.ready()` is invoked first, before the function `getdates` is even mentioned, causing the console to throw

`jQuery.Deferred exception: getdates is not defined ReferenceError: getdates is not defined`

According to this question

[jQuery - multiple $(document).ready ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263385/jquery-multiple-document-ready)

When multiple consecutive calls to $(document).ready are made, upon DOM ready each function will be called in the order they were set. Even if you reverse the order of the calls to `ready`, since the named function `getDates` is only named during the function call, it isn't callable by that name anywhere else. Edit: Also note that if the first function queued for documentready throws an exception, jquery will **not** invoke the next one. So if the anonymous function fails, the named one will be skipped entirely.

Bear with me as I have really not answered many questions on this site, and its possible I've gravely misunderstood your code. But I think what you're trying to do is define a function `getDates` and invoke it when the value of an HTML element called '#StaffId' is changed. To accomplish this, you only need one call to `$(document).ready()`, which either calls the function `getdates`, which has to be defined in its scope, or you could get rid of `getdates` entirely and call its contents anonymously.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        getdates();
    });

    var unavailableDates;
    //this function might as well be anonymous since getdates is not available anywhere else by that name.
    //The function it refers to is passed and executed on document ready, but the alias getdates goes away.
    $(document).ready( function getdates() {

        console.log("getting dates");
    });
</script>
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //if unavailableDates is not used outside this function, it probably shouldn't be in the global scope.
    var unavailableDates;
    function getDates(){
        //now getDates is available everywhere, by its name
        console.log("getting dates");
    };

    //or $(document).ready(getDates);
    $(getDates);
</script>
```

or just

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function (){
            //no need for named getdates polluting global namespace if you only intend to call it once.

            //do whatever you want here
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because you aren't definibg a value for the dropdown first. Try this:

```
$('#StaffId').val('12345');
$('#StaffId').trigger('change');
```

Other remark: why the 2 document ready's ?