# Javascript Fibonacci method

Tags: javascript

So I created the fibonacci series, but the way I found on w3resources is a bit confusing to me as a beginner. What exactly happens when `n = 2`? `s` becomes `fibonnacci_series(1)`, but what does this even imply? In the first place why do we have `var fibonacci_series  = function(n)` , why not just have a function called `function fibonacci_series(n)`?

```
var fibonacci_series = function (n)   
{  
  if (n===1)   
  {  
    return [0, 1];  
  }   
  else   
  {  
    var s = fibonacci_series(n - 1);  
    s.push(s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2]);  
    return s;  
  }  
};  

 console.log(fibonacci_series(8));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly happens when `n = 2`? `s` becomes `fibonacci_series(1)`, but what does this even imply?

This means you're going to get the same result as if you had called `fibonacci_series(1)` by itself. So `s` will be `[0, 1]`. Afterwards, you add the sum of those two numbers to the end of the array, resulting in `[0, 1, 1]`. This relationship (Nm = N(m-1) + N(m - 2)) is [what defines the Fibonacci sequence.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)

Writing it in the this way means that this same process will happen recursively. Following this logic, try writing down what would happen if `n = 3`. What would happen during the first call to `fibonacci_series`? How would the next call to `fibonacci_series` change what the function returns?

> In the first place why do we have `var fibonacci_series  = function(n)`, why not just have a function called `function fibonacci_series(n)`?

For your purposes, there's really no difference. The technical answer is that the first is a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) and the second is a [function declaration.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) If you're interested in the details of how they're different, [check out this Stack Overflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: wow. This thing suddenly makes all sense. It was really creative how they thought of using .length. Honestly would have never thought of that. I was just doing it iteratively before. Thanks so much

Comment: @Munt No worries! Not going to lie, I remember this thing blowing my mind when I first learned about it.

Answer (score 2):

These two lines do almost the same thing (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) for more details but as said in the comments, this is probably not relevant for you right now):

```
var fibonacci_series = function (n)   

function fibonacci_series(n)
```

Both define a function called `fibonacci_series` that take `n` as parameter, it's just a variant.

The fibonacci series function is a recursive function, it means that it calls itself in its body (e.g there is `fibonnacci_series(n-1)` inside the function).

When `n = 2`, `s` equals the value of `fibonnacci_series(1)`, which is what is returned by the `if` statement.

Comment: There are actually some subtle differences, but they are probably irrelevant for the OPs question. See [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5857498/1250301)

Answer (score 2):

When `n = 2`, s becomes the result of the recursive call of `n - 1` (which is `[0,1]`). Then, `s.push(s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2])` is pushing the addition of the 2nd last element with the last element, which is how the fibonacci sequence is obtained.

This is a reccursive implementation of the fibonacci sequence. It can also be done through iteration.

Comment: When s = 2, s = fibonacci_series(1). What does this mean? I dont understand what fibonacci_series(1) exactly means. Does this just mean s = [0,1]?

Comment: Basically, yes. The statement `s = fibonacci_series(n - 1)` is a recursive call. Since `n = 2` in this case, the function will be called again with `n = 1`. If you look at the return value for the case when `n = 1`, you'll see that it returns `[0,1]`. Thus, `s = [0,1]`.