# Understanding jQuery initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

As is evident when the document gets loaded in the client browser,

```
$(function(){
some code here
});
```

takes over.

Say I have two JavaScript files `main.js` and `style.js`

*main.js* is for the functionality and *style.js* for some hypothetical styling when the page loads. I want both the files. I include them in my *index.html* first *style.js* then *main.js* both of them start with:

```
$(function(){
    some code here
    });
```

My question is, what is the order of execution of `document.ready` is it that *main.js* and *style.js* start doing things parallely or is it sequential, once *style.js* has finished what it should do then *main.js* takes over??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can have multiple `document.ready` but that affects the readability of the code. More has been explained [here](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/multiple-document-ready)

Answer (score 4):

It is sequential.  There is no parallel processing in javascript.  They will be called in the order you included your scripts on the page.

This is a good answer too: [Can you have multiple $(document).ready(function(){ ... }); sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327756/can-you-have-multiple-document-readyfunction-sections)

Comment: +1. It would be more precise to say "called in order scripts files are executed". Depending on presence of "defer" attribute order in which script tags are and load order may not be the same.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript won't execute the code parallel by default; to execute a code in background you need to create [webworkers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#introduction). Currently your code works on a first come, first served basis.