# jQuery : $(document).ready() suggestion

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you have multiple $(document).ready(function(){ … }); sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327756/can-you-have-multiple-document-readyfunction-sections)

May be this question is little bit funny.

I just want to know that can we use `$(document).ready()`more then one time on a page

If yes then what is the pros and cons for that?

Comment: will work, but size file increases, readability understandability issues etc :(

Comment: Well, of course you can. But there's no point doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you can use it more than once. In fact, if you don't care at all about
>   keeping your code small, you could litter your javascript file with
>   them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      // some code here
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // other code here
    });
```

> It's great to be able to group your functions within a file or even
>   across multiple files, `and jQuery's flexible $(document).ready()
>   function allows you to do that, pain free.`

***[read more](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/multiple-document-ready)***

Try this out:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('1!');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('2!');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('3!');
});
```

above code is the same as below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('1!');
    alert('2!');
    alert('3!');
});
```

Comment: Great answer  this is what i was looking fo r

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can call it as many times as you want, but it's not a good practice though. No cons as such, I think.