# Asp .Net with jquery document ready event

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using jquery with asp .net. I have some javascript code in some custom controls that I want to execute when the documents loads.

To execute the code I use this snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /*do work here*/ 
});
```

My question is that if I set that handler in the control, won't it override the handler for document.ready in the page that contains the control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use anonymous function in your user control script, that way you are safe always

```
var results= function () {
  //Do your work here      
}
```

Although it's perfectly legal to use multiple document.ready functions in your page, please check below

[Can you have multiple $(document).ready(function(){ ... }); sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327756/can-you-have-multiple-document-readyfunction-sections)

Comment: @Satpal Thanks for pointing that, it was new to me also (my bad). Corrected to want i want to answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not overriding just adding. Such code will produce two alerts for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("hello");
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("world");
});
</script>
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/c8cTE/).