# more than one $(document).ready(function() { in a single page

Tags: jquery, pageload, document-ready

i have read this answer

FROM [Can you have multiple $(document).ready(function(){ ... }); sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327756/can-you-have-multiple-document-readyfunction-sections)

> You can have multiple ones, but it's not always the neatest thing to
>   do. Try not to overuse them, as it will seriously affect readability.
>   Other than that , it's perfectly legal.

But this is not the duplicate of that question,but with reference to that question i have to ask

1. whether this type of implementation affect the pageLoad time of the
   page
2. will it need any http requests for that
3. do it have any drawbacks

Comment: It does not affect the pageload noticeably if you have several DOM ready handlers, and there's no HTTP requests for a DOM ready handler in itself, but as the quote says, it's always neater with just one DOM ready handler per file at the most, and it's generally all you'll need.

Comment: Could you clarify bullet #2?

Comment: you can check here http://jsperf.com/docready/11

Comment: I have yet to find a need for multiple `.ready` usage.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not more than attaching another listener to any other event. So no.
2. No, because of the fact the `$(document).ready(...)` is just a listener to the "ready" event it's no more different than binding several `.on("click", ...)` to a DOM element.
3. It depends, as long as the `$(document).ready(...)` listeners are modular an has no dependencies upon another theirs nothing strictly wrong about it. But I would argue to only use one function for readability sake...

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple ones, but it's not always the neatest thing to do. Try not to overuse them, as it will seriously affect readability. Other than that , it's perfectly legal. See the below:

http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/multiple-document-ready