# how to have multiple script tags on a page without one being skipped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

is there any way to have two javascript scripts on a page without them clashing and one of the scripts being skipped?

If so how?

I am trying to use the fiddle below but the transition will not work, I believe it is because I have the javascript below on the same page. Maybe Im wrong though

http://jsfiddle.net/duGkA/

```
<script>
var bgArr = [
 'images/bg1.jpg',
'images/bg2.jpg',
'images/bg3.jpg',
'images/bg4.jpg',
'images/bg5.jpg',
'images/bg6.jpg',
'images/bg7.jpg',
'images/bg8.jpg',
'images/bg9.jpg',
'images/bg10.jpg'];

document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bgArr[10] + ')';
bgCur = 0;
backgroundSwitch = function () {
if (bgCur == bgArr.length) bgCur = 0;
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bgArr[bgCur++] + ')';
}
window.setInterval(backgroundSwitch, 6000); // Switch every 6 seconds.
</script>
```

Comment: Skipped? Skipped how?

Comment: It should be possible to have any number (within reason) more than one.  They shouldn't 'clash' unless the code within them is causing that to happen.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5drHj/

First time using jsfiddle so hope it works.

Comment: ... You've tagged 'jquery' so maybe your question is whether you can have more than one $(document).ready(function(){}); instance?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327756/can-you-have-multiple-document-readyfunction-sections

Comment: sorry for the bad question can people not vote me down though? Ill get banned, sorry though guys, im trying to learn!!

Comment: You get banned for being downvoted too much?  I didn't know.  I didn't downvote you btw :)

Comment: What about your jsFiddle doesn't work?

Comment: @MrVimes no Im soooo confused.... Maybe I should repost the whole script, my brain is fried so the question wasn't really very good could you please look at www.mildenhire.com/daisy and tell me whats gone wrong? the left container is meant to slide in from the left but it isnt. i really really need help :( help a tired girl in need?

Comment: It looks like you are not including the jQuery library in your page. I see an `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error in the console for your page.

Comment: If some scripts break or clash with previously loaded scripts, the rest will also break in the clients DOM. See what is compatible with what and use the right ones. I have tried to use Prototype and JQuery together, wasn't very good though

Comment: You put your jQuery link inside your CSS declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `<script>` elements on your page. The first animates the sidebar and requires jQuery. The second sets up the rotation of the background image but does not require jQuery.

The code in the first `<script>` element causes an `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error to get thrown and quits executing. The browser still executes the code in the second `<script>` element though, so it appears that the first `<script>` is skipped.

You need to include the jQuery library. You can either serve it from your own server, or use something like:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

You also need to put your code for the sidebar in a document-ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.leftContainer")
        .css("margin-left",-$(this).width())
        .animate({
            marginLeft:0
        }, 1000);
});
```

Otherwise the browser will try to execute it before the elements it references exist.

Note: The jsfiddle was set to execute the code on page load, so it did not need the code wrapped in a document-ready handler.

Comment: Hi John I corrected that a little while ago but it still did not help, its in the head section of the page

Comment: @user3206866 - I just added to my answer.

Comment: I also made it document ready with no joy :(

Comment: @user3206866 - You need to move the `<script>` element for jQuery. You  have it in the `<style>` element. Move it one line up.