# Knockout.js duplicate script

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

when I put both ko.js together one of them gets overshadowed by the first I mean the second one stops working and just the first one works how can I merge them together and have them working properly without any problems. separately they work great just not together why is that?

```js
var z = 1; //value to make div overlappable

$('#addText').click(function (e) {
    /** Make div draggable **/
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'ui-widget-content1',
        appendTo: '.container4',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent1',
            start: function( event, ui ) {
                $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
            }
        }
    });
});


$(document).on("dblclick", '.text1', function()
{
    $(this).hide();    $(this).closest('.item1').find('.edit_text1').val($(this).text()).show();
});

$(document).on("click", ".edit_text1", function()
{
    return false;
});


$(document).on("click", function()
{
    var editingText = $('.edit_text1:visible');
    if (editingText.length)
    {
        editingText.hide();
        editingText.closest('.item1').find('.text1').text($(editingText).val()).show();
    }
});


    var count = 1;
var selectedDraggable;

ko.bindingHandlers.draggable={
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel2) {
        $(element).draggable();
        $(element).addClass('item1' + count);
        count++;
        $(element).on('click', function () {
            selectedDraggable = $(this);
        })
    }
};


var vm=function(){
    var self=this;
    self.items1=ko.observableArray();
    self.textContent1 = ko.observable('');
    self.init=function(){
        self.items1([]);
    }
    self.remove=function(item){
        console.log(item);
        self.items1.remove(item);
    }
    self.addNew1 = function() {
      self.items1.push( self.textContent1() );
      self.textContent1('');
    }
    self.init();
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());​
















var z = 1; //value to make div overlappable

$('#addText').click(function (e) {
    /** Make div draggable **/
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'ui-widget-content',
        appendTo: '.container',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent',
            start: function( event, ui ) {
                $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
            }
        }
    });
});


$(document).on("dblclick", '.text', function()
{
    $(this).hide();    $(this).closest('.item').find('.edit_text').val($(this).text()).show();
});

$(document).on("click", ".edit_text", function()
{
    return false;
});


$(document).on("click", function()
{
    var editingText = $('.edit_text:visible');
    if (editingText.length)
    {
        editingText.hide();
        editingText.closest('.item').find('.text').text($(editingText).val()).show();
    }
});


    var count = 1;
var selectedDraggable;

ko.bindingHandlers.draggable={
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel1) {
        $(element).draggable();
        $(element).addClass('item' + count);
        count++;
        $(element).on('click', function () {
            selectedDraggable = $(this);
        })
    }
};


var vm=function(){
    var self=this;
    self.items=ko.observableArray();
    self.textContent = ko.observable('');
    self.init=function(){
        self.items([]);
    }
    self.remove=function(item){
        console.log(item);
        self.items.remove(item);
    }
    self.addNew = function() {
      self.items.push( self.textContent() );
      self.textContent('');
    }
    self.init();
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
​
```

Comment: You've asked four questions recently, all extremely similar, with [this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38780024/419956) possibly even a direct duplicate. The ones that do have code in them, have *a lot* of it. I suggest reading through the help center a bit, improving your existing questions instead of keep asking new ones (or: explain how they are related/different).

Answer (score 0):

As @Jeroen stated, you should reduce your code to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

However, knockout applies it's bindings to the entire DOM.  It doesn't make sense to call `applyBindings` on the entire DOM more than once.  If you have different view models for different parts of your page, [pass the DOM element](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) you want each view model to bind to during `applyBindings`:

```
 ko.applyBindings(new vm(), document.getElementById('someElementId'))
```