# How to pass multiple functions in document.ready

Tags: jquery

I want to pass more than one functions on document ready.

Doing something like

```
$(document).ready(myFunction; anotherFunction;);
```

did not work.

If I add parentheses, it will actually execute the function.

It works if I do

```
$(document).ready(myFunction);
$(document).ready(anotherFunction);
```

but , is there a better syntax where I can pass all the functions at once?

Something like

```
$(document).ready(myFunction, anotherFunction);
```

Thanks

Comment: You can revise the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327756/can-you-have-multiple-document-readyfunction-sections

Comment: there is no diff calling them within the document ready like $(document).ready(function(){ myfunction1(); myfunction2(); });

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`document.ready` takes a single function as its argument. There is therefore no way to specify all of your functions as a list of parameters. You have a couple of different options for writing it differently with the same behaviour.

1. Create a new function to wrap your others

   function initialise() {
   myFunction();
   anotherFunction();
   }

   $(document).ready(initialise);
2. Use jQuery's `$(document).ready` shortcut syntax

   $(myFunction);
   $(anotherFunction);

3a) Wrap them all in one function passed to document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function () { myFunction(); anotherFunction(); });
```

3b) Or equivalently using the shortcut syntax

```
$(function() { myFunction(); anotherFunction(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `.ready` is only supported on the `document` and only accepts **one** function as an argument to call when the document is ready.
You can however use it multiple times, but there's no need to, just use an anonymous function wrapper instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    myFunction();
    anotherFunction();
});
```