# Not getting data from handson table

Tags: javascript, html, handsontable

I want to get the values from handsontable but i am getting this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: hot is not defined

I don't know why i am getting this error as i have defined hot .

here is my js code

```
 <body>
    <div id='table_set' style='margin-left:150px;'>

        <button id='save'>Save</button>


        <div class='handsontable' id='create_table'></div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
             var data = [[]];
             var container = document.getElementById('create_table');
             var hot = new Handsontable(container,
          {
           data: data,
           minRows: 30,
           minCols: 13,
           maxRows:100,
           copyPaste:true,
           colHeaders: true,
           rowHeaders: true,
           rowHeaders: true,
           contextMenu: true,
           dropdown: true,
           colHeaders:["Testcase Name","Cell Name","Customer","Flops","Title","Status","Mfix CCR(open/close)","Scenerio-Brief Description","Expected Results","CCR Status","CCR No.","Remarks","Testcase Path"]
       });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#save').click(function() {
        var pr= hot.getData();
        alert(pr);
    });
    });
```

I want to get the values i have written in the table , in the alert box whenever i hit the save button.Please help, where i am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is probably multiple `document.ready` function 
i think variable declared in one `document.ready` cannot be accessed in other

generally dont use mulitple `document.ready` you can achieve these with single `document.ready`

refer : [Can you have multiple $(document).ready(function(){ ... }); sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327756/can-you-have-multiple-document-readyfunction-sections)

handson table reference : http://jsfiddle.net/yk64yv8q/4/